# How to implement common intent, states and base classes in MVI?

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm

I'm migrating from MVVM to MVI in my pet project and seems I need some help. I have several common code-blocks, for example, one of them is an abstract fragment and viewModel for searchbar logic. MVVM had non-stricted organization, it allows to use the common method in SearchViewModel, but in MVI I have to replace it by dispatchIntent. The problem, that all intents and states in my visian are sealed classes - so, I can't create the common sealed class for several screens, which uses SearchBar-logic. So, can I resolve this conflict?

**SearchViewModel:**

```
abstract class SearchViewModel<INTENT : MviIntent, STATE : MviState>(defaultState: STATE) :
    BaseSubscriptionViewModel<INTENT, STATE>(defaultState) {
    private var keyWord: String = ""

    override suspend fun dispatchIntent(intent: INTENT) {
        this.keyWord = intent.keyWord ?: ""  // <= Error
    }
    /**
     * Changed key word async.
     *
     * @param keyWord Key word
     */
    fun updateKeyWordAsync(keyWord: String?) = launchInBackground { // <= Should be replaced by dispatchIntent.
        keyWordWasChanged(keyWord)
    }

    /**
     * Key word was changed.
     *
     * @param keyWord Key word
     */
    protected open suspend fun keyWordWasChanged(keyWord: String?) {
        this.keyWord = keyWord ?: ""
    }
}
```

**Fragment:**

```
abstract class SearchToolbarFragment<INTENT : MviIntent, STATE : MviState, VM : SearchViewModel<INTENT, STATE>>(
    private val vmKClass: KClass<VM>
) : ToolbarFragment<INTENT, STATE, VM>() {
    open val menuId: Int = R.menu.menu_search

    private val queryTextListener = object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
        override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String?): Boolean {
            viewModel.dispatchIntentAsync(INTENT(query)) // <= Error. How to resolve it?
            // viewModel.updateKeyWordAsync(query)            
            return true
        }

        override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String?): Boolean {
            viewModel.dispatchIntentAsync(INTENT(query)) // <= Error. How to resolve it?
            // viewModel.updateKeyWordAsync(query)   
            return true
        }
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(
            store = viewModelStore,
            factory = viewModelFactory,
            defaultCreationExtras = defaultViewModelCreationExtras
        )[vmKClass.java]
    }

    override fun onCreateMenu(menu: Menu, menuInflater: MenuInflater) {
        super.onCreateMenu(menu, menuInflater)
        menuInflater.inflate(menuId, menu)
        initSearch(menu)
    }

    /**
     * Init search.
     *
     * @param menu Menu
     */
    private fun initSearch(menu: Menu) {
        // ....
    }
}
```

While I was writing it, I had one more questions - In which moment should I call `initSearch(menu)`? From one side I need themenu-object, but from another inside I have dependency to the current keyWord.